# Akka-HTTP vs JAX-RS

Tags: rest, jersey, akka, jax-rs, akka-http

I recently started learning Akka-HTTP and struggling to get one answer.

We know that libraries like Jersey, RestEasy follows a common interface/APIs which is **JAX-RS**.
And Akka-HTTP is also a suite of libraries. So, does Akka-HTTP also follow JAX-RS?

If not, then how is Akka-HTTP different from JAX-RS?

Any answer to it will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS is just a specification; Jersey, RestEasy etc. are just different implementations of this specification.

Akka-http does not implement JAX-RS; furthermore, equivalent mappings in JAX-RS and Akka-http would be written in completely different code styles:

- API's written with JAX-RS are regular methods annotated with annotations
- API's written with Akka-http are using router functions instead of annotations and communicate with actors (more about actor model [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model))